# Is there a way to import data from an API to Power BI and change the API link automatically to include headers according to specific filter?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Hope you are OK!

Currently I'm using Power BI to build a dashboard and for this work I'm dealing with a huge dataset that is constantly updating, hence it is complicated to import the whole data to Power BI; actually I do not really need to import all of it, since there's data from 2015 to 2024 and I am actually interested in plotting information regarding only a year or only certain customer.

To deal with that, I already have an API with the headers "start-time", "end-time" and "customer" to allow me to filter the data. By using it, I can considerably reduce my dataset and import it to Power BI with such delimiters. I am importing it via web -> Advanced -> API link with its corresponding delimiter (such as in the photo below, that is not mine).

[API request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr0i5.png)

Let's consider I was analyzing the data of customer "AAAA" (whose data I imported using /?customer=AAAA in the API link). Now I want to analyse the data of customer "BBBB". For that, the only way I know to change the link to /?customer=BBBB (so that I can consult the data about customer "BBBB") is manually. Is it possible to do some kind of integration in order to, by only changing filters from Power BI itself, modify the request link to import data from the API with other specific delimiters?

If that is not possible, do you have any recommendation on how to integrate the Power BI filtering with the API headers, so that I do not have to import the whole dataset (which would be impossible due to its size)?

Comment: What you are wanting is a Dataset with DirectQuery. There are only a handful of data sources that support DirectQuery, and REST API is not one of them. See Chris Webb's post [Can I Build A Power BI DirectQuery Dataset On Top Of A REST API?](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2021/04/25/can-i-build-a-power-bi-directquery-dataset-on-top-of-a-rest-api/)